# How to solve the problem of too much data in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to read a table in Oracle database through pandas. When using `topandas()` method, I can read other tables normally, but if I read a table with large amount of data, invoking `topandas ()` method will be of no help.

Tried to change the configuration of the spark-submit submission task, changed -- `driver-memory` to `6G` -- `executor-memory` ran again after 6G and the same error occurred

````
python: 
def loadOracle():
    df = spark.read.format('jdbc)\
        .option('url', cfg.oracle_url)\
        .option('dbtable', cfg.oracle_collections)\
        .option('user',cfg.oracle_schema_u)\
        .option('password', cfg.oracle_schema_p)\
        .option('driver', "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")\
        .load()
    d = df.toPandas() #DataFrame
    listDeviceCode = d['DEVICE_EAM_CODE'] #Series
    Print(listDeviceCode)
    return listDeviceCode
```
Traceback(most recent call last):
        file '/home/demo/deme_oracle',line 31, in loadOracle
         d = df.topandas()#DataFrame
````

Comment: `toPandas()` loads all the data to the spark driver. You can only increase the memory if you want to continue to work with pandas. Maybe it makes sense to work with pyspark dataframes as they offer you the opportunity to process your data dristributed on a cluster.

Comment: Have you check the size of that table?